# after updating to PyCharm 2021.2, get Statement expected, found Py:DEDENT

Tags: python, pycharm

After updating to PyCharm 2021.2, all of my python code is peppered with errors that say: "Statement expected, found Py:DEDENT". I'm attaching a minimal example of code that produces the error. It's always associated with a line where I go from more to less indented.

Needless to say, this wasn't the case before updating. It occurs for all my projects, so, it's not something project specific.

The minimal example is one I created in a fresh file and I tried adding a new interpreter. I'm not sure what else to try.

Thanks for any advice!

[image: A minimal example]

Comment: Seems to be a regression in 2021.2. Try **File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings...**. If possible - please send the old settings backup archive to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-49970 to help us figure out the root cause.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. It is a recent PyCharm regression in 2021.2 release.

Comment: @PavelKarateev even if it is a regression, the problem is that in SO's logic it's still a duplicate. Because the error message and causes are essentially the same. Thus any answers should still be concentrated on the linked canonical thread to avoid dispersion of the information. From what I understand in this case I still think the closure was correct (given its current upvotes the question will stay around as a sign post). But I would strongly advise the OP to follow your instructions and submit the archive as requested.

Comment: Tldr we found the cause. To work around the problem add `-ea` to **Help | Edit Custom VM Options** or `<pycharm_installation>/bin/pycharm(64).vmoptions`.